# Is a templated, polymorphic callback a good idea?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I'm making a Gui Api for games. The user can always use inheritance on the widget and override, but I want callbacks. I want to use a templated callback system:

so if they want to have one for the mouse they inherit from a version of the templated callback base with mouseargs:

So the base would look like this:

```
template <typename T>

class AguiEventCallback {

public:
virtual void callback(AguiWidget* sender, T arg) = 0;

};
```

Is it a good idea to mix templates with polymorphism like this? Would I be better off creating callbacks for each of the types I need (mouse, keyboard, gamepad, etc)?

Thanks

Comment: I think you'd be better off creating callback interfaces for each of the relevant events. It's difficult to say what would be a good solution (there are zillions of various event schemes, and each inventor presumably thought this particular scheme was best for something). But templating on the argument type will probably not buy you anything (what if number of args is not 1?). Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at boost::function and boost::bind. Accept a function object with a defined parameter list for particular events, and callers can do what they want.

This gives callback implementations lots of flexibility and the object generating the events requires even less knowledge of the callback implementation.

For example:

```
 typedef boost::function<void (AguiWidget* sender)> CallbackFunc;
 void register_callback(CallbackFunc const& f);
```

And the client:

```
class Caller {
    void do_register() { register_callback(bind(&Caller::event, this, 123, _1)); }

    void event(int arg, AguiWidget* sender) { ... }
};
```

Just showing function/bind, many other issues ignored; eg. memory management, object lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Using a template the way you have is fine sometimes. There are issues due to the fact that you must give your template a virtual destructor and that

- If you inline your virtual destructor (as you do with most template functions) some compilers find it hard to stick to the One Definition Rule, particularly if the library is used across libraries.
- If you do not inline your virtual destructor you have to instantiate every type you are going to use with that template. This is my own preferred approach.

For a callback, you do have the option of using boost::function. This avoids having to derive classes from your template, create them with new and probably stick them into a shared_ptr somewhere. The downside of boost::function as a callback, I have found, is that it is harder to debug into if something goes wrong. Beware of that issue.

Comment: You do not need to make the destructor virtual, you can also have it `protected` and non-virtual: The callback interface cannot be used to `delete` objects, just to perform the call. Even if you decide to use it (you want to store objects by one of the interfaces and delete through it, the cost of adding a virtual destructor to a class that already has virtual methods is negligible, the common pattern would be having the virtual destructor defined inside the class definition. I have never encountered the problem that you mention in the first bullet, can you extend? what compiler? code?

Answer (score 0):

Momentarily accepting your virtual dispatch solution, what your templated approach guarantees is a uniformity in the callback function name and arguments.  Sadly, that will force a lot of other code to disambiguate which callback is being invoked / overridden, probably causing more trouble than good.

That said, as janm said other options exist.  Functors are more powerful (you can change them on an existing object at run-time, you can have lists of observers) but also have to be initialised at the right time (pure virtual functions effectively remind the programmer to supply them at compile time), and introduce a bigger variety of run-time states to reason about and understand.

You might also be able to use a template policy or the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern to supply behaviours at compile time, allowing inlining, dead code elimination, type-specific behaviours and other optimisations.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers here you might have a look to the boost::signal library. It implements a signal/slot mechanism which is indeed useful for GUIs. Performance is not as good as you would expect (costs more than a call to a virtual method) but for a GUI it's just fine.

The boost::signal library can also be used together with boost::bind and this combo is very powerful.

I don't like using inheritance very much for callbacks. It spawns a lot of classes with just 1 method most of the time. It's C++ not Java. you have functions, use them :)